# How do I format the following if/else in Jasper?

Tags: if-statement, groovy, jasper-reports

I am trying to format the following if/else in Jasper and having trouble.  This is what I have but my syntax is wrong can someone help?

```
$F{PAYMENT_METHOD_DATA}  == {"deposit_name":"PayNearMe","is_important":true,"logo":"https:\/\/nj-cdn-casino.ballyinteractive.com\/cms\/V3\/Deposit-Methods\/icon-Paynearme.png"} ? "PayNearMe" :
$F{PAYMENT_METHOD_DATA} ==  {"deposit_name":"ACH (Optimal)","withdrawal_name":"ACH (Optimal)","display_order":"101","is_important":true} ? "ACH" :
$F{PAYMENT_METHOD_DATA} ==  {"deposit_name":"wire transfer","withdrawal_name":"wire transfer","display_order":"42","is_important":true} ? "Wire Transfer" :   
$F{PAYMENT_METHOD_DATA} ==  {"deposit_name":"Personal check","withdrawal_name":"Personal check","display_order":"6","is_important":true} ? "Personal Check" :
$F{PAYMENT_METHOD_DATA} ==  {"deposit_name":"Cashier''s check","withdrawal_name":"Cashier''s check","display_order":"7","is_important":true} ? "Cashiers Check": "Cash"
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ternary operator should be [like](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

```
condition ? execute true code : execute false code
```

jasper condition should be like,

```
$F{PAYMENT_METHOD_DATA}  == "deposit_name"?"PayNearMe":"PayMe"
```

if you want to check multiple conditions, then you should write like,

```
$F{PAYMENT_METHOD_DATA}  == "deposit_name"?($F{PAYMENT_METHOD_DATA}  == "deposit_name_other"?"PayNearMeYes":"PayMeYes"):"PayMe"
```

Comment: Thanks all!  I ended up having to do the following because of all the quotes etc in the statement, they were causing a problem.  $F{PAYMENT_METHOD_DATA}.contains("PayNearMe") ? "PayNearMe" :
$F{PAYMENT_METHOD_DATA}.contains("ACH") ? "ACH" :
$F{PAYMENT_METHOD_DATA}.contains("wire") ? "Wire Transfer" :
$F{PAYMENT_METHOD_DATA}.contains("Personal") ? "Personal Check" :
$F{PAYMENT_METHOD_DATA}.contains("Cashier") ? "Cashier's Check" :
"Cash"